# Property args is not allowed in launch.json in vscode

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am just trying to add some basic configuration to my `launch.json` file in `vscode`, but I am getting an error as **Property args is not allowed.** Below is my configuration.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "index",         
            "args": [
                "src/index.ts"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"           
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was a silly mistake. According to this [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

> VS Code debuggers typically support launching a program in debug mode
>   or attaching to an already running program in debug mode. Depending on
>   the request (attach or launch) different attributes are required and
>   VS Code's launch.json validation and suggestions should help with
>   that.

So when I changed my request to `launch`  from `attach`, everything was perfect. Only the request type `launch` supports the configuration `args`.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "index",         
            "args": [
                "src/index.ts"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"           
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to pass command line args to a remote [ssh] debug, and am getting the same "Property args is not allowed" error.  However, switching the request to 'launch' then moves the error to "Property connect is not allowed".  :(
Starting the debug seems to work/attach, but my arguments are not included.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "connect": {
                "host": "gmc0410",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": ["AuditNP", "arg2"]
        }
    ]
}
```