# Property string is not allowed

Tags: javascript, json, themes, visual-studio-code

I was changing my theme properties like `comment`'s foreground color in VS Code.

Using `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` in `settings.json` file.

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Tinacious Design (legacy, 2016)]": {
    "comments": "#797979",
    "string": "#898989", 
  }    
}
```

The `comments` color was changed perfectly, but when I assigned a color to the `string` value, it shows an error:

> *"Property string is not allowed."*

### Error images

- [error message upon hovering string key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6WLH.png)
- [comment inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSkYm.png)
- [string inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqVfS.png)

Comment: Maybe because the parent property of `"string"` is surrounded by square brackets? ( `[`, `]`)

Comment: Maybe this is related to: [_"Property args is not allowed in launch.json in vscode"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007130/property-args-is-not-allowed-in-launch-json-in-vscode)?

Answer (score 2):

The "string" keyword is a reserved name and cannot be used to define a property. Sort of like why your own name can't be given to someone else. The correct way of setting the string color is

```
"strings": "//color Hex"
```

Further reading: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score 1):

"string" is the keyword which you cannot use a variable name. Give some other name like colorValue or anything else and it will work

Comment: But it's not a variable name, it is a property that is scoped. Maybe the property is reserved in VS Code specifically. Maybe there is an allow/block-list of valid property names specific to VS Code?