# How to debug C programs with args in vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a C program with args, but the program runs without the args specified in launch.json. Vscode gives me the warning "Property args is not allowed"

[image: Property args is not allowed]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property args is not allowed in launch.json in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007130/property-args-is-not-allowed-in-launch-json-in-vscode)

Comment: Your `"type": "by-gdb"` seems strange to me. As far as i know there is no such debugtype.
Proper debug types in cpp are `cppvsdbg` when using the Visual Studio Windows debugger, and `cppdbg` when using GDB or LLDB.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_type.

And yes, the type chooses which further json parameters are valid.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I don't think that's relevant because that is javascript and the issue was with the request parameter. by-gdb is the default given to me by vscode. Using cppdbg instead worked for me.